# Spring Boot Data Jpa - @ManyToOne Join with UUID id

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, uuid

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.4 with Spring Data Jpa. I have a User model with a user table. User ID is a UUID defined like so:

```
@Id
@Type(type="uuid-binary")
@GenericGenerator(name="uuid2", strategy="uuid2")
@GeneratedValue(generator="uuid2")
@Column(columnDefinition="BINARY(16)", unique=true, updatable=false)
private final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
```

So far all works well.

I now add a Token model and a token table where I store tokens (e.g. email confirmation tokens etc.). The Token model includes a field User user, which I want to join to the user table using a @ManyToOne relationship like so:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",  referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

When I was still using a Long for User id, this all worked perfectly. However, now I keep getting the following error:

```
2018-08-23 18:33:26.700  WARN 97837 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
2018-08-23 18:33:26.700 ERROR 97837 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`auth`.`token`, CONSTRAINT `FKe32ek7ixanakfqsdaokm4q9y2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
2018-08-23 18:33:26.701 ERROR 97837 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2018-08-23 18:33:26.703 ERROR 97837 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
```

I have googled, but found nothing of help, so any help would be very much appreciated, as I have been struggling with this and trying seemingly all possible permutations for the whole afternoon today, but the error remains the same, irrespective of what I try.

Comment: P.S. I should add, that if instead I use say the User email as a @NaturalId to join the tables, that works perfectly. So it really does seem related to the fact, that I am using a UUID for User id.

Comment: P.P.S. I should have also added, that I am using a MySQL database using the InnoDB engine.

Comment: Anybody, please? Any help with this would be very much appreciated. It looks like a bug to me, but maybe I am simply missing something obvious.

Comment: I retagged the question. I don't see any relationship to anything spring.

Comment: Please include the code you use to save the entities and the SQL statements executed, including the values of bind parameters.

Comment: As I wrote above, I am using Spring JPA for persistence, so SQL obviously gets generated by User and Token (CRUD) repositories respectively. I have not overwritten any of the default Spring JPA User or Token repository methods. And as I said, all works well and as expected, as long as I do not use UUID's as User ID's or as long as I use an alternate @NaturalId to join the two tables.